# Cordova + iOs Publishing Error ITMS90035 - Invalid Signature. Code object not signed at all

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, app-store, publish

I am using Cordova 5.1.1 tô build an hybrid app. I have already managed tô send the app tô the Google Play Store, but I am having BIG trouble tô send it tô App Store for iPhone.

I am getting error ITMS90035 - Invalid signature. Code object not signed at all. I have looked all over the internet for solutions without any success.

Here is what I did:
- Cloned my app folder from Github ( it is in a public repository, no big deal -> https://github.com/guizero/miviromobile2015
- Installed Xcode and Cordova 5.1.1
- Opened the repository folder and wrote 'cordova add platform ios' (ok)
- Ran ' cordova build ios ' (ok)
- Opened Xcode and configured certificates.
- Clicked on run tô device (the app worked correctly ).
- Clicked on ARCHIVE and then tried tô send tô app store. ERROR Invalid Signature ITMS 90035.

I have already tried:
- Delete all .sh or other files with !#/bin/... could not find any, not using bower. No success.
- Delete all certificates and provisions and creating new ones (no success).
- Selecting the distribution provision from Build Settings and Distribution Certificate. No success.
- Deleting plugins and trying each of them. No success.
- Adding ' -deep' tô other code signing flags. No success.
- Downloaded apple root certificates. No success.

I am running out of options and I have been trying tô make it work for three days now.

Can anybody help me? The code is all public on github... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove any "*.sh" from the xcode project. That worked for me. Also though I removed everything, but found one left in a lib//script-directory.